# Prove that : $f(n) \le \frac{1}{4}(n-1)^2+1 $

Tags: graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Let $f(n)$ denote the largest number of edges on $n$ vertices among triangle-free graphs that are non-bipartite . For all $n \geq 5 $ prove that:

- $f(n) \le \frac{1}{4} (n-1)^2+1$
- Let's construct a graph where $" = "$ occurs.

It's easy to see that $Mantel's $problem gives us a structured result similar to mine (though I don't know if it helps)

$Mantel$ Problem : Deduce from the proof of Mantel theorem the following strengthening of the assertion. Let G be a triangle-free graph of order n. Then $ e(G)≤n^2/4$

According to the problem , the given graph cannot be divided into non - bipartite graph   , so it will have an odd degree cycle .

I am thinking of dividing the vertices of the graph into 2 parts, one part contains the vertices in that cycle, the other part contains the remaining vertices. But my work has not progressed at all.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you very much. Sorry I'm a newbie. Looking forward to your help.

Comment: I think we will get an insight from working out the case $n=5,7$ whether a modification to the near equal parts bipartite extremal graph succeeds in achieving equality.

Comment: @hardmath You can easily test the case n=5 , which is a star shape .

Comment: Equivalently, a five-cycle, and the equality case is achieved for $n=5$.

Comment: @hardmath have you tried dividing the image in my direction , does it help you ?

Comment: You are on the right track to prove the first part by splitting the graph into an odd-cycle and the vertices which are not on that cycle. After deciding the case $n=5$, one can proceed to prove cases $n \gt 5$ by induction using [Mantel's Thm.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem#Mantel's_theorem)  Hint: Make the cycle one of *shortest odd length* in the graph.

Comment: @hardmath Can you be more specific? please

Answer (score 5):

> Let $G$ be a non-bipartite graph of order $n$ without triangles. Then
> $|E(G)|\leq\frac{(n-1)^2}{4}+1$.

*Proof*. Since the graph does not contain triangles, for any edge $uv$ we have $\deg(u)+\deg(v)\leq n$.
The following three cases are possible.

(1) There is a pair of adjacent vertices $u,v$ for which
$\operatorname{deg}u+\operatorname{deg}v=n$.

(2) There is a pair of adjacent vertices $u,v$ for which
$\operatorname{deg}u+\operatorname{deg}v=n-1$.

(3) For any adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$ the inequality
$\operatorname{deg}u+\operatorname{deg}v\leq n-2$ holds.

Consider each case.

(1) If $\operatorname{deg}u+\operatorname{deg}v=n$,
then our graph is bipartite with parts $N(u)$ and $N(v)$,
where $N(x)$ are all neighbors of $x$.

(2) Let $\operatorname{deg}u+\operatorname{deg}v=n-1$ and $w\notin N(u)\cup N(v)$.
If $N(w)\cap N(u)=\varnothing$ or
$N(w)\cap N(v)=\varnothing$, then the graph is bipartite.
If $k=|N(w)\cap N(u)|>0$ and $l=|N(w)\cap N(v)|>0$ and $d=\operatorname{deg}u$,
then since the graph without triangles
$$
|E(G)|\leq \operatorname{deg}u\cdot \operatorname{deg}v+k+l-kl\leq
\operatorname{deg}u\cdot \operatorname{deg}v+1=(n-1)d-d^2+1=
$$
$$
-\left(d-\frac{n-1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{(n-1)^2}{4}+1\leq\frac{(n-1)^2}{4}+1.
$$

(3) If
$\operatorname{deg}u+\operatorname{deg}v\leq n-2$ for any adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$, then
$$
(n-2)|E(G)|\geq\sum_{uv\in E(G)}(\operatorname{deg}u+\operatorname{deg}v)=
\sum_{u\in V(G)}(\operatorname{deg}u)^2\geq
$$
$$
\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{u\in V(G)}\operatorname{deg}u\right)^2=\frac{4|E(G)|^2}{n}.
$$
So
$$
|E(G)|\leq\frac{n(n-2)}{4}<\frac{(n-1)^2}{4}.
$$

**Addendum** (in response to @ZFR's 20.07.2022 questions).

If $uv$ is an edge, $\deg(u)+deg(v)=n-1$, $N(u)\cap N(v)=\varnothing$, $w\notin N(u)\cup N(v)$, and for example $N(w)\cap N(u)=\varnothing$, then the graph is bipartite and its parts are $N(v)$ and $N(u)\cup\{w\}$.

Why does the inequality
$$
|E(G)|\leq\deg(u)\cdot\deg(v)+k+l-kl
$$
hold?

In a graph $G$ there can be only edges connecting vertices of sets $N(u)$ and $N(v)$ except for edges connecting vertices $N(w)\cap N(u)$ and $N(w)\cap N(v)$ (such edges cannot exceed $\deg(u)\cdot\deg(v)-kl$), edges connecting the vertex $w$ with some vertices of $N(u)$ and $N(v)$ (there are exactly $k+l$).

The inequality $k+l-kl\leq1$ follows from the fact that $(k-1)(l-1)\geq0$.

Comment: I am bit confused with part 2). Can you give some more details? 1) If $N(w)\cap N(u)=\varnothing$ or $N(w)\cap N(v)=\varnothing$, then why is it bipartite? 2) I did not understand the inequality which follows after it.

Comment: @ZFR You asked some very good questions, thank you. A year later, I realize that the things you mentioned do require further clarification.

I have supplemented my answer, as this addendum is not appropriate for commentary.

Comment: Really nice explnantion! Thank you so much for your reply! +1

Answer (score 5):

The following solutions are adapted from [some class notes](https://www.math.kit.edu/iag6/lehre/extremalgt2016s/media/01-solution.pdf) by Jonathan Rollin.

Let $G$ be a graph witn $n$ vertices that is triangle-free and not bipartite.  So $G$ contains a [cycle of odd length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61920/if-a-graph-has-no-cycles-of-odd-length-then-it-is-bipartite-is-my-proof-correc).  We are first asked to show that the number of edges is at most $(n-1)^2/4 + 1$.

If $n=5$, then the graph must be a cycle of length $5$, and the inequality is sharp: $(5-1)^2/4 + 1 = 5$ edges.

Otherwise $n\ge 6$. Let $C$ be a shortest odd cycle contained in $G$, say of length $k$, which by assumption must be greater than $3$.  Since $C$ is the shortest odd cycle, the graph $G$ does not contain any "chord" edge of $C$ (because that would create a strictly shorter odd cycle on one "side" or the other of that chord).

Let $X$ be the set of vertices in $G$ but not in $C$. *Claim:* Each vertex $v\in X$ has at most two neighbors in $C$.  Suppose for contradiction that $v\in X$ has three or more neighbors in $C$.  Three such neighbors would split the cycle $C$ into three paths, each of length *greater* than one (since $G$ is triangle free).  Those three paths combined have all $k$ edges of $C$, and since $k$ is odd, at least one of those paths contains an odd number of edges less than $k-2$.  But then that path together with the two edges joining $v\in X$ would give a shorter odd length cycle than $C$.  This contradiction establishes the claim.

Now we can upper bound the total number of edges in $G$.  First by Mantel's Thm. the number of edges between the vertices in $X$ is at most $\lfloor |X|^2/4 \rfloor$ as this subgraph of $G$ is also triangle free.  Second the number of edges between vertices in $X$ and in $C$ is at most $2|X|$ by the preceding paragraph's claim.  Finally, by the observation that $G$ contains no chords on $C$, the number of edges between vertices of $C$ is exactly $k$, the length of $C$.

Note that $|X| = n-k$ and $k\ge 5$, so $n-k \le n-5$. Thus the number of edges in $G$ is at most:

$$ \begin{aligned} \lfloor \frac{(n-k)^2}{4} \rfloor + 2(n-k) + k &\le \frac{1}{4}\left((n-5)^2 + 4(n-5) + 4(n-1)\right) + 1 \\ &= \frac{1}{4}(n-1)^2 + 1 \end{aligned}$$

For the second part of the problem one can show equality is attained whenever $n\ge 5$ is odd.  Suppose $n = 2t+1$, and consider the complete bipartite graph $K_{t,t}$ having two equal size parts.  Remove an edge $uv$ and add a new vertex $w$ with edges $uw$ and $vw$.  That graph has $n$ vertices and $(n-1)^2/4 + 1$ edges (since we removed one, then added two edges).  Finally the Reader should verify that it is not bipartite and is triangle free.

Comment: The proof is wonderful, but I didn't see which step utilizes the method of induction. (you said, "we proceed by induction." ) You use  Mantel's Theorem for $n-k$ vertices, not use inductive hypothesis.

Comment: @licheng: Thanks for reading it over!  By "method of induction" I meant to justify the appeal to a minimal (shortest) odd cycle in $G$.  I'll try to find a clearer way to say that.  The problem hypothesis is that $G$ is *triangle-free*, so this shortest cycle has to be length five (or more).  Somewhat related is the Wikipedia write-up on [minimal counterexample](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_counterexample).

Comment: @licheng It took me too long to get around to editing.  I decided the best way was just to remove the phrase about induction.  The proof is structured around a minimal length odd cycle, and a claim is proven by contradiction.  But this claim is then combined with Mantel's Thm. to get the estimate on edges, so it isn't cleanly a case of a minimal counterexample or a proof by induction.  Thanks again for you close reading.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution.

Induct on $n$. The cases where $n=5,6$ can be easily verified. Consider removing two vertices $u,v$ with an edge between them. Since there are $n-2$ other vertices and each of these is adjacent to at least one of the two, removing the two vertices remove at most $n-1$ edges.

If exactly $n-1$ edges are removed, then we can show that $N(u),N(v)$ is a bipartition because $G[N(u)], G[N(v)]$ are anticliques. Thus $G$ is bipartite.

If there exists $u,v$ sharing an edge such that after removing them, less than $n-1$ edges are removed, then if $G[V\backslash \{u,v\}]$ is not bipartite we are done by inductive hypothesis. Thus, we can assume that for every $u,v$ not sharing an edge, $G[V\backslash \{u,v\}]$ is bipartite, then any odd cycle of $G$ passes through at least one vertex in any edge.

Take the shortest odd cycle of $G$ with vertex set $C$. Then $G[C]$ is a cycle, $G[V\backslash C]$ is an emptyset, and each vertex in $V\backslash C$ is adjacent to at most two vertices in $C$ (with distance 2, or we can build a smaller odd cycle). This implies that the number of edges is at most $|C| + 2 |V\backslash C| \le 2n-|C| \le 2n-5$. When $n\ge 7$ we clearly have $2n-5 \le 1+\frac{(n-1)^2}{4}$.